# Get the last two path depths. Regex

Tags: regex

i just want to have the last two path depths matched.

Example input:

```
/root/sync/test1/hallo12
```

Matched should be:

```
/test1/hallo12
```

My not working regex:

```
(/.*){2,2}$
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
(?:/[^/]+){2}$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/dbon1j/1).

**Details**

- `(?:/[^/]+){2}` - two consecutive occurrences of

  - `/` - a slash
  - `[^/]+` - 1+ chars other than `/`
- `$` - end of string.

In case there can be a trailing slash use

```
(?:/[^/]+){2}/?$
             ^^
```

where `/?` matches 1 or 0 slashes.

Note that in case you are using the pattern inside  `/` regex delimiters you have to escape the slashes in the pattern.